# How to return entire table row in array by foreign key and how to access from template in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, jinja2

I have tried like this. But it is returning the only one combined value.

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    nameininitials = models.TextField(null=True)
    nameinuse = models.TextField(null=True)
    employeeno = models.TextField(null=True)
    departmentname = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return '{} {}'.format(self.nameinuse, self.employeeno)


class Region(models.Model):

    regionname = models.TextField(null=True)
    regionalincharge = models.ForeignKey(Employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null = True)
```

When I use `datalist = Region.objects.all()` , I want all fields from Employees table in different variables or array to use in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# If this is your query in your views function or class

datalist = Region.objects.all()


# then you can access 'Employees' data in your template by using '.' operator. 

For example

views.py

def view_function(request):
    datalist = Region.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', { 'datalist': datalist })



template_name.html

{% for data in datalist %}
    <p>{{data.regionalincharge.nameininitials}}</p>
    <p>{{data.regionalincharge.nameinuse}}</p>
    <p>{{data.regionalincharge.employeeno}}</p>
    <p>{{data.regionalincharge.departmentname}}</p>
    <hr />
{% endfor %}
```